# Sparse matrix from list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, statistics, sparse-matrix

Hi I have a file having structure as follows:

```
    > df
    LATITUDE1 LONGITUDE1 LATITUDE2 LONGITUDE2   X   V    Y   W  Cell1  Cell2
1      -71.2       -180   -71.344     178.97 -72 -72 -180 178 -26100 -25742
2      -71.0       -180   -71.300     177.70 -71 -72 -180 177 -25740 -25743
3      -70.8       -180   -71.300     177.70 -71 -72 -180 177 -25740 -25743
4      -70.6       -180   -71.444     174.30 -71 -72 -180 174 -25740 -25746
5      -70.4       -180   -71.040     175.76 -71 -72 -180 175 -25740 -25745
6      -70.2       -180   -70.499     176.33 -71 -71 -180 176 -25740 -25384
7      -70.0       -180   -70.350     177.03 -70 -71 -180 177 -25380 -25383
8      -69.8       -180   -70.995     176.40 -70 -71 -180 176 -25380 -25384
9      -69.6       -180   -71.309     171.87 -70 -72 -180 171 -25380 -25749
10     -69.4       -180   -71.015     171.42 -70 -72 -180 171 -25380 -25749
```

I have some R-code that summarizes non-zero transition probabilities from Cell1-levels to Cell2-levels:

```
counts <- by(df, df$Cell1, function(d) c(table(d$Cell2)/nrow(d)))

> counts1
df$Cell1: -26100
-25742 -25743 -25746 -25745 -25384 -25383 -25749 
     1      0      0      0      0      0      0 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$Cell1: -25740
-25742 -25743 -25746 -25745 -25384 -25383 -25749 
   0.0    0.4    0.2    0.2    0.2    0.0    0.0 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$Cell1: -25380
-25742 -25743 -25746 -25745 -25384 -25383 -25749 
  0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.25   0.25   0.50
```

I would like to be able to make a sparse matrix of transition probabilities from this list (zero and non-zero): Since my list elements are of unequal length this is rather difficult. I have tried `do.call` but this its not acceptable, since I would have to look up "manually" every Cell-level and determine whether or not it should be zero.

```
> do.call(rbind, counts)
-25746 -25745 -25743 -25384
-26100    1.0   1.00   1.00    1.0
-25740    0.2   0.20   0.40    0.2
-25380    0.5   0.25   0.25    0.5
```

Thank you.

EDIT: Using akrins code below I get a matrix of the form

```
do.call(rbind, counts)
       -25742 -25743 -25746 -25745 -25384 -25383 -25749
-26100      1    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.00   0.00    0.0
-25740      0    0.4    0.2    0.2   0.20   0.00    0.0
-25380      0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.25   0.25    0.5
```

I am expecting results of the form

```
    A    B    C    D
A  aa    0   ac    0
B  ba   bb    0   bd
C   0   cb    0    0
D   0   db    0    0
```

Comment: I guess you may need `table(factor(d$Cell2, levels=unique(ofes.df$Cell2))` inside the `by`

Comment: Thank you, your code goes some of the way. Now, the matrix resulting from this is not a square matrix with the same "states" in the rows and columns. Can we fix that as well?

Comment: You need to show an example that gives a nonsquare matrix.  Using the example, I am getting square

Comment: I just realized I changed my grid size and the cell-levels that result from that are different. But you may take the edited question at face value. In general, we will have a non square matrix. And the states on either side are not the same.

Comment: Can you show the expected result as well, so that it becomes easier for others to check?

Answer (score 1):

The table function creates one entry per level when given factors.

If I understood correctly, this is what you want:

```
df <- read.table(text="    LATITUDE1 LONGITUDE1 LATITUDE2 LONGITUDE2   X   V    Y   W  Cell1  Cell2
1      -71.2       -180   -71.344     178.97 -72 -72 -180 178 -26100 -25742
2      -71.0       -180   -71.300     177.70 -71 -72 -180 177 -25740 -25743
3      -70.8       -180   -71.300     177.70 -71 -72 -180 177 -25740 -25743
4      -70.6       -180   -71.444     174.30 -71 -72 -180 174 -25740 -25746
5      -70.4       -180   -71.040     175.76 -71 -72 -180 175 -25740 -25745
6      -70.2       -180   -70.499     176.33 -71 -71 -180 176 -25740 -25384
7      -70.0       -180   -70.350     177.03 -70 -71 -180 177 -25380 -25383
8      -69.8       -180   -70.995     176.40 -70 -71 -180 176 -25380 -25384
9      -69.6       -180   -71.309     171.87 -70 -72 -180 171 -25380 -25749
10     -69.4       -180   -71.015     171.42 -70 -72 -180 171 -25380 -25749")

levels <- unique(c(df$Cell1, df$Cell2))
df$Cell1 <- factor(df$Cell1, levels=levels)
df$Cell2 <- factor(df$Cell2, levels=levels)
t <- table(df$Cell1, df$Cell2)

require("Matrix")
mat <- Matrix(t, sparse=T)
```

This yields:

```
>t

         -26100 -25740 -25380 -25742 -25743 -25746 -25745 -25384 -25383 -25749
  -26100      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
  -25740      0      0      0      0      2      1      1      1      0      0
  -25380      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      2
  -25742      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  -25743      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  -25746      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  -25745      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  -25384      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  -25383      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  -25749      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

If you know that the cells are between e.g. -30000 and 30000 you can simply set `levels=-30000:30000`.

EDIT:
If you want the probabilities, just normalize the lines or use prop.table to do it.

```
t <- prop.table(table(df$Cell1, df$Cell2), margin=1)
```

But you end up with NaN on the lines with no entries. You should normalize the lines yourself, or if you prefer the quick and dirty way, `t[is.nan(t)] <- 0`

So that you end up with:

```
> mat
10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 10 column names ‘-26100’, ‘-25740’, ‘-25380’ ... ]]

-26100 . . . 1 .   .   .   .    .    .  
-25740 . . . . 0.4 0.2 0.2 0.20 .    .  
-25380 . . . . .   .   .   0.25 0.25 0.5
-25742 . . . . .   .   .   .    .    .  
-25743 . . . . .   .   .   .    .    .  
-25746 . . . . .   .   .   .    .    .  
-25745 . . . . .   .   .   .    .    .  
-25384 . . . . .   .   .   .    .    .  
-25383 . . . . .   .   .   .    .    .  
-25749 . . . . .   .   .   .    .    .
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I am getting a lot of `NaN` in the sparse matrix, though.

Comment: Thank you. `prop.table` is rather slow for my data set, since the dimensions of my table are 50,000 by 50,000. Can I speed this up somehow?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8605/column-wise-matrix-normalization-in-r), what is said works from row-wise normalization too. 

You'd just have to replace 2 by 1 in sweep for example, or multiply by diag(1/colSums(mat)) on the left and not on the right. 

I think the latter would be particularly efficient, especially since you can create sparse diagonal matrix with the matrix package by setting the doDiag argument to TRUE.